# RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found for Rails 4 and Jetty Solr server on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I am using Rails 4.0.5 with sunspot_rails 2.1.1. I am having problem with the solr server which I launched with jetty on Production. This is the error I am getting whenever I run **rake sunspot:solr:reindex**:

```
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     Not Found

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:GadgetModel</query></delete>"

Backtrace: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in 'adapt_response'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'`
```

I have set up my production server following the instruction at http://blogs.pigrider.com/blogs/26.

From the link above, I tried to deploy my solr on jetty which was working well until I upgrade from Rails 3 to Rails 4.

I realise that from the link above, both the 1) solr-jetty server (`service solr start`) and 2)sunspot_solr server (`rake sunspot:solr:start`) are started. However, I would want the independent 1) solr-jetty server to run for my rails app.

My config/sunspot.yml file is as such:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /opt/solr
    solr_home: /opt/solr/solr/collection1

    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

Notice that I have set both the **path** and **solr_home** to what I think works for my configuration when I follow the instruction from the blog.

I have also checked the log fiel under /opt/solr/logs/solr.log. The log does not capture anything when the 404 error is returned from reindex command.

Strangely when I stop my 1) solr-jetty server (`service solr stop`) and run 2) sunspot_solr, it works (`rake sunspot:solr:start`). But of course I would not want to use the sunspot_solr server for my production since everytime the service is stop, i would need to reindex again.

My gem list is as such:

```
sunspot (2.1.1)
sunspot_rails (2.1.1)
sunspot_solr (2.1.1)
rsolr (1.0.10)
```

I am suspecting that my sunspot.yml file is wrongly configured but I have tried multiple times to change them but the server keep returning 404 error.

The other solution elsewhere in stackoverflow is not working for me. 1 week is spent on this issue but still not solved :( Appreciate any solr/rails expert to help.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved! Based on the blog, the solr server would be install under collection1, so the path and solr_home should be 'path: /solr/collection1' and 'solr_home: solr'

Comment: Thank you! you are my personal god for this week! The settings for that where not making any sense to me, would have taken days to figure out on my own.